# How to test controller action in Grails 3.3.6 without using services

Tags: testing, grails, groovy, integration, spock

I have created Grails Application with one domain and controller. In development environment i have inserted two entry for domain.I want to perform integration testing such that it fetch records from the database and return the total size.Below is my source code which i tried.

Below is my domain

```
Student.groovy.

import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional

@Transactional
class Student {

String name
String rollnumber
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Below is my controller:-

```
import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional

@Transactional
class StudentController {

 def readall(){
       println "inside read all "+Student.getAll().size()
       respond Student.getAll()
     }
}
```

Below is my Integration Testing code:

```
import grails.testing.gorm.DomainUnitTest
import grails.testing.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.testing.web.controllers.ControllerUnitTest
import grails.validation.ValidationException
import spock.lang.Specification
@Integration
class StudentControllerSpec extends Specification implements ControllerUnitTest<StudentController>, DomainUnitTest<Student> {

void "getAllStudentList"(){
        given:
        def studentList=[]
        when:
        request.method = 'GET'
        controller.readall()
        println studentList.size()
        then:
        studentList.size()==1

    }
}
```

Below is my application.yml file

```
---
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: false
        use_query_cache: false
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: ''

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

i'm getting below exception while running test case

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

2019-04-21 16:05:07.979 ERROR --- [    Test worker] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'methodValidationPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'methodValidationPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastoreServiceRegistry': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateDatastore' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateDatastore': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager, at table: student, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(transaction_manager)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@Transactional` from your domain class. `@Transactional` are used to begin transactions on services/controllers - but it does not make sense in a domain class.

The error is GORM is trying to create a column of `transaction_manager` because `@Transactional` adds a property of transactionManger to the class and is of a type that doesn't make sense to hibernate.

Comment: After removing @Transactional , i'm facing related to hibernate. Hibernate cannot initialize in current thread.

Comment: You'll have to add more details to your question with the exact code and errors.